# Azure website and web api Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, adal

I'm working on a Azure website that uses Azure Active Directory to authenticate users (AdalAngular). The server hosting the website requests data from a 3rd party Web API that requires Basic or Kerberos authentication. Currently, we provide the server credentials to access the 3rd party API. We need to change the authentication strategy so that the users credentials or claims are passed from the server to the web API.

Comment: What is your technical problem, and what have you attempted so far ?

Comment: We need to pass the user credentials/claims token to the 3rd party web api.

Comment: Since it's 3rd party, the access token from Azure AD will not work. I suggest you to extend your Azure AD schema and store the 3rd party credentials in Azure AD. When authenticating to the 3rd party API, you can just read the necessary information from Azure AD, and use that information to log into the 3rd party. For how to extend Azure AD schema, read [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/03/05/extend-azure-active-directory-schema-using-graph-api-preview/)

Comment: IMPORTANT - NEVER add credentials or anything secret in the Azure AD schema extensions.